# Parse outside website from Amazon Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, echo, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing a new skill for Amazon Echo at the moment.

All I would like to do, is ask Alexa to start parsing a website. I would like to call a script from Amazon Lambda function (Node.js).

- The first step would be: open a website and start reading the source code
- Second: write a script and call that script from Amazon. When the script finished I can parse the result as JSON (further usage).

Could any of you help me out, who can I do it please ?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to fetch the webpage. You can use the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module.

After you have the page contents then you can use the [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) module for parsing out the page contents. Cheerio is great because it has a jQuery-like syntax for selecting elements.

Then you simply generate your JSON object from the data you've parsed out from the page.

For a complete example check out the Alexa Skills Kit (ASK)  [Hacker News skill](https://github.com/miguelmota/ASK-HackerNews) I've built.